# Why AlertDialog can't display in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, error-handling, android-alertdialog

I 've tried several time but still did not show up , so I wanted to make a AlertDialog , where AlertDialog that appears when you click the ListView , in AlertDialog just an image only, but already a few hours of this I did not find his way out, this my code :

### informasi.java

```
public class Informasi extends Activity {
protected static final ItemDetails ItemDetails = null;
protected Object Object;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.informasi);

    ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

    final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 

            Intent i = null; 
            if (position == 0){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A1.class);
                } 
            else if(position == 1){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A1A.class); 
                }
            else if(position == 2){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A2.class);
                }       
            else if(position == 3){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A3.class);
                }       
            else if(position == 4){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A4.class);
                }
            else if(position == 5){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A5.class);
                }

            else if(position == 6){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A6.class);
                }

            else if(position == 7){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A7.class);
                }

            else if(position == 8){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A7A.class);
                }

            else if(position == 9){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A8.class);
                }

            else if(position == 10){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A9.class);
                }

            else if(position == 11){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A10.class);
                }
            else if(position == 12){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A11.class);
                }
            else if(position == 13){ 
                i = new Intent(Informasi.this,com.hospifinder.A12.class);
                }

            else if(i !=null)
            startActivity(i);     
        }
    });
}

private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults(){
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

    ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS SARI ASIH KARAWACI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Imam Bonjol No.38 (Pos Polisi) Kota Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(1); //1a
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS SARI ASIH CILEDUG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. HOS. Cokroaminoto No.38 (Depan Mall Ramayana) Ciledung Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(2); //1
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSU KAB TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Jend. Ahmad Yani No. 9 Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(3); //2
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS USADA INSANI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. KH. Hasyim Ashari No. 24 Cipondoh-Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(4); //3
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS AN-NISA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Gatot Subroto No. 96 Cibodas sari Km 3 Cibodas, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(5); //4
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS DINDA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Galuh No.2, Jatiuwung, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(6); //5
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS BHAKTI ASIH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raden Saleh No.10 Karang Tengah Ciledug, Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(7); //6
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS ISLAM SARI ASIH AR-RAHMAH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jalan Ks Tubun No. 44Kwang Jaya, Karawaci, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(8); //7
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSK SITANALA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Dr Sitanala, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(9); //7a
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSU HERMINA TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. KS Tubun No.10 Pasar Baru, Tangerang ");
    item_details.setImageNumber(10); //8
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS. ARIYA MEDIKA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Industri Raya I Blok A. No. 1-11, Jatake - Kodya Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(11); //9
    results.add(item_details); 

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS MELATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Merdeka No.92, Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(12); //10
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS AWAL BROSS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. MH. Thamrin No.3 Kebon Nanas, Cikokol, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(13); //11
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSUD Kota Tangerang");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Pulau Putri Raya, Kel. Kelapa Indah Kec. Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(14); //12
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SELARAS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raya Lapan Rumpin, Suradita, Cisauk Suradita, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(15); //13
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA SELARAS");
    item_details.setItemDescription("JL. Raya Serang, Km 185, Bojong, Cikupa, Talaga, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(16); //14
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("CIPUTRA HOSPITAL");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Mekar Bakti, Panongan,Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(17); //15
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS MITRA HUSADA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Kp. Melayu Barat, No. 11A, Teluk Naga, Kec. Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(18); //16
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT MULIA INSANI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jalan Raya Serang KM 16,8, Cikupa, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(19); //17
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RS PARAMITA TANGERANG");
    item_details.setItemDescription("JL Raya Serang, Km. 28, 5 Kavling FL No. 8, Balaraja, Kawasan Industri CCM");
    item_details.setImageNumber(20); //18
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT QADR");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Komplek Islamic Village, Karawaci, Kec. Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(21); //19
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("SILOAM HOSPITALS LIPPO VILLAGE");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Siloam No. 6, Lippo Karawaci 1600, Kec. Tangerang, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(22); //20
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSUD BALARAJA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Rumah Sakit No. 88, Desa Tobat, Balaraja, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(23);//21
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("EKA HOSPITAL CENTRAL BUSINESS DISTRICT (CBD)");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Lot IX BSD City Serpong");
    item_details.setImageNumber(24);//22
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT OMNI INTERNATIONAL");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Alam Sutera Boulevard Pondok Jagung, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(25);//23
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT INTERNATIONAL BINTARO");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. MH. Thamrin Blok B3 No. 1 Sektor 7 Bintaro Jaya");
    item_details.setImageNumber(26);//24
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA ICHSAN MEDICAL CENTER");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Jombang Raya No 56 Bintaro Sektor IX");
    item_details.setImageNumber(27);//25
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT MEDIKA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("BSD City, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(28);//26
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT ISLAM ASSHOBIRIN");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Raya Serpong KM.11 Pondok Jagung");
    item_details.setImageNumber(29);//27
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA BUAH HATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Aria Putra Ciputat");
    item_details.setImageNumber(30);//28
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RSIA BUAH HATI");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Siliwangi Pamulang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(31);//29
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT BHINEKA BAKTI HUSADA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Cabe Raya No.17/34, Pamulang, Tangerang Selatan, Banten");
    item_details.setImageNumber(32);//30
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT HERMINA");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl.Kertamukti Ciputat Timur");
    item_details.setImageNumber(33);//31
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SYARIF HIDAYATULLAH");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Ir. H. Juanda No.95 Kec. Ciputat, Tangerang");
    item_details.setImageNumber(34);//32
    results.add(item_details);

    item_details = new ItemDetails();
    item_details.setName("RUMAH SAKIT SAKIT SARI ASIH CIPUTAT");
    item_details.setItemDescription("Jl. Otista Sasak Tinggi No. 3, Ciputat");
    item_details.setImageNumber(35);//33
    results.add(item_details);





return results;


}
}
```

### A1.java

```
   package com.hospifinder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.bongkorr.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class A1 extends Activity {
private ListView   lv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.informasi);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
arrayDialog.add("Dialog");
      lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayDialog));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int   position, long id) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(A1.this);

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(A1.this);


            //setting custom layout to dialog
            LayoutInflater inflater = A1.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            //adding text dynamically
            TextView txt = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txt.setText("Put your dialogView text here.");
            ImageView image = (ImageView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info));

            //adding button click event
            Button dismissButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
               dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

### custom_alert_dialog.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/a1"
        android:src="@drawable/a1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Dismiss" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### informasi.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#0033CC"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <ListView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/listV_main"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Is there something wrong with my code ? whether because the ListView so influential and in case of error ?

Comment: is your `listview's onItemClickListener` method getting called ?\

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi how it's supposed to ? please help me

Comment: in `onItemClick()` method put a log like this-> `Log.d("ListItem","Clicked");` and see if this is getting printed in logcat

Comment: are you sure `setContentView(R.layout.informasi);`  at informasi.java and `setContentView(R.layout.informasi);` at A1.java are the same layout ?

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat bukan nya bisa ya? kan saya mau nya AlertDialog itu muncul di ListView nya ... sedangkan listview sendiri letak nya di Informasi.java?

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi no error in logcat

Comment: @RuhbiAnugrahPutraguna `R.id.lv_data` layout ini di simpen nya di xml mana ?

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat maksud nya `R.id.listV_main` yang ada di `informasi.xml` bisa bantu saya, sulit sekali terpecahkan

Comment: coba di kasih `Log.d("ListItem","Clicked");` di onItemClick nya kalau clicked nya muncul di logcat berarti item ke click kalau ga berarti ga ke klik

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat cuman itu aja yang muncul `Displayed com.bongkorr/com.hospifinder.Informasi: +477ms` di LogCat nya

Comment: saya sudah coba script nya work tampil kalau di saya

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat kenapa disaya engga ya??

Comment: coba boleh liat import nya buat yang di A1.java

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat udah saya update code A1.java nya, tolong bantuin yaaa, urgent banget

Comment: sama padahal importnya

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat makanya itu, aneh nih apanya ya yang salah?? Manifest nya?

Comment: engga manifest ga ada hubungan nya sama dialog

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat Saya udah update yang Informasi.java apa ngaruh ya sama `private ArrayList<ItemDetails>` nya ya??

Comment: itu udah di coba di run di device lain ?  takut nya resolusi nya juga ngaruh

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat udah coba debug di hape juga sama aja ga muncul, di genymotion ga muncul juga

Comment: itu size file nya gede ga ? kira2 bisa di upload ga ? tapi kalau gede file nya jangan maksain upload sayang kuota, 
Soalnya saya mau nyoba debug app nya, masih penasaran

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat engga sih ... saya juga penasaran ... bantuin saya ya, kamis saya sidang soal nya ... email mas apa?? mohon bantuan nya ya

Comment: thidayat13@gmail.com

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat sudah saya kirim :)

Comment: kenapa ya di saya mah muncul aneh :/ padahal blm merubah script apapun

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat itu pake package yang saya kasih? saya tuh mau nya AlertDialog ny cuma gambar aja, jdi informasi nya berupa gambar gitu mas, gimana ya?